# GMailApp Script: Override default search behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

What would be the starting point to extend Gmail using Google Scripts to **override** default search behavior? i.e, calling my custom code instead, so in theory i should be able to disable search altogether by returning null. In other words, customizing the existing search behavior and **not** performing a custom search.

I want to achieve this and not sure what is the starting point: after one time authentication, gmail to exclude all discussion threads from any future search results which either are before certain date or contains specific keywords.

Is it even possible to create trigger like *onSearch()* - if there's such a thing - and which scripts functions i need to override to modify the search results?

Thanks,

Comment: You can definitely do a custom search using Google Apps Script. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String) for details. You can write scripts to filter out the results. However, it is recommended that you write some code first up and seek help on any specific issue you might face. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. I've already seen the reference guide which shows custom search. However, I don't want to create a custom search but customize the **existing** default search behavior of gmail for my account.

Comment: What you're asking for is not directly possible. However, you can use Gmail search operators to filter out search results. Read https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en . The same operators work just fine when invoked through the search function of Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can't Do That. Google Apps Script does not have any way to modify the GMail user interface.

Taking Srik's comment one step further, you could bookmark favorite searches using the **Quick Links** lab.

> Adds a box to the left column that gives you 1-click access to any bookmarkable URL in Gmail. You can use it for saving frequent searches, important individual messages, and more.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to achieve, but it seems overriding the default behavior is not possible. Thanks nonetheless.